# How can I add padding for one table column in Cuba Platform?

Tags: css, cuba-platform

I created a table and the content of the **first** column is not at the same line with the title. When I add padding to that table all of my columns have that padding and not just the first column. How can I write the css to just speak to the first column?

[image]

[image]

This is what I already tried:

```css
.bewertungstable-padding .v-table-cell-wrapper:first-child {
    padding: 4px 7px 4px 12px;
}
```

Here is my table in xml:

```html
<table 
    id="fileFrageHistoryTable" 
    width="100%" 
    height="100%" 
    dataContainer="fileFrageHistoryDc"
    stylename="borderless no-horizontal-lines no-vertical-lines bottom-border-radius bewertungstable-padding"
    showSelection="false" 
    sortable="false">
  <columns>
       <column id="frageHistory"/>
       <column id="prozessAuswahl" width="50"/>
       <column id="antwort"/>
       <column id="antwortBegruendung"/>
       <column id="position" visible="false"/>
  </columns>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: This seems to be a `th` not a `td`. The styling makes it look different so just copy its selector from the browser development tools.

Comment: I added my XML table. With the browser development tool I could not find out the selector for just one column.

Comment: The image looks like if the third `row` has a different padding. But you are talking about a column. There is also only one column visible in the image. Furthermore: What is `.v-table-cell-wrapper`? To answer this it would be the best to add more HTML code to the question...

Comment: Yes thats true, but the third row is unimportant. It has to be bigger. I talk about the left padding of alle the three rows in the first column. All the other columns have the right padding. `.v-table-cell-wrapper` is a selector I found out with the development tool. I can modify the padding of every column in this table with it. But i just have to modify the first. When i use the selector all the other perfect columns become more padding then i need. I updated the pictures.

Comment: Can you just post your CSS and HTML to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) and give us a URL here? This way we can edit the CSS to find the problem. If you can not at least add rows to your HTML example.. it doesn't show the table rows at all. It's hard to guess how we can style it.

Comment: I added the whole xml. Css is just this one statement i already added.

Comment: Table header captions and columns value are aligned by default. I suppose that the problem is that the first header caption has padding that was necessary when you had a large border-radius for table. Just remove CSS code that adds extra padding.